# Putting each item of a csv file line into a variable

Tags: php, variables, csv, while-loop

I have the following code which I am using to open up an uploaded csv file, and then output each line on a separate line.

```
  if(isset($_GET['uploadfile'])) {
 $file = fopen($_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'], 'r+');
 while(! feof($file))
{
 echo fgets($file). "<br />";
 }
 fclose($file);
  }
```

The ouput looks like this :

```
        ABC,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        ACR,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        AGL,-,1.60,-,3.25,-,6.35 
        AGO,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        AHS,-,-,4.00,-,-,- 
        ALC,-,1.60,-,3.00,-,6.35 
        ALV,-,-,4.00,-,-,- 
        AMG,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        ANF,-,-,-,-,7.95,- 
        ANG,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        ANN,-,1.60,-,3.25,-,- 
        ANV,0.87,1.60,-,-,-,- 
        APO,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        ARP,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        ARR,-,1.60,-,3.00,-,6.35 
        ASH,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        ATG,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        ATR,-,1.60,-,3.00,-,- 
        AUE,-,1.60,-,3.25,-,- 
        AUN,-,1.60,-,3.25,-,- 
        AUR,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        BAB,0.87,1.60,-,-,-,- 
        BAL,-,1.60,-,-,-,6.35 
        BBE,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        BBL,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        BCH,-,1.60,-,3.25,-,- 
        BDI,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        BEM,-,-,-,-,7.95,- 
        BEN,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        BGE,-,-,-,3.25,-,- 
        BIA,-,-,-,-,-,- 
        BIF,-,1.60,-,3.25,-,- 
        BLC,0.87,1.60,-,3.25,-,-
```

So there is a product code and then 5 csv cells, each spaced with a comma. What im trying to do is assign a variable to each as it runs, so

```
   BLC,0.87,1.60,-,3.25,-,-
```

could become

```
     $productcode.$value1.$value2.$value3.$value4.$value5
```

for each loop of the while loop. Im not sure how on earth to pull each line apart though, so id appreciate any pointers anyone has on how to do it.

Comment: Just to be sure, you want $productcode.$value1.$value2.$value3.$value4.$value5 to be arrays that hold the values from the csv ?

Comment: Have you considered that PHP has a built-in [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function for reading CSV files?

Comment: What I am attempting to do is to insert the each variable into the database on each line, so need to be able to  pull each line apart first into its individual value.

Comment: Then read what fgetcsv() actually does

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(isset($_GET['uploadfile'])) {
    $file = fopen($_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'], 'r+');
    while(! feof($file))
    {
        $line = fgetcsv($file);

        list($productcode, $value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5) = $line;

        // Ready to use the variables and insert to database
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

Here you go, now  you can use the varibles as you want, and insert in the database after the list functions has been done, so at the comment i made.

Comment: If you're using fgetcsv(), you don't want to explode: `list($productcode, $value1, $value2, $value3, $value4, $value5) = fgetcsv($file);`

Answer (score 2):

```
  if(isset($_GET['uploadfile'])) {
     $file = fopen($_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name'], 'r+');
     while(! feof($file))
     {
       $line = fgets($file);
       list($productcode,$value1,$value2,$value3,$value4,$value5, $value6) = explode("," , $line);

        // Store into for further proccessing, if needed, else insert into DB
       //array_push($productcode_array, $productcode);
       //array_push($value1_array, $value1);
       // and so on for each value..
     }
     fclose($file);
  }
```